# Pella Door won't lock (3 point lock)

Tags: repair, doors, lock

I have several Pella doors in my home with the 3 point locks (top and bottom "shootbolts" and a dead bolt near the handle).  They have been problematic.  The locking mechanism on a couple of rarely used doors would hardly work anymore (very stiff and wouldn't lock anymore).  So I disassembled them, cleaned up the runners and other parts, applied a good lube, reassembled and they worked again. They are a pain to take apart, re-adjust and reassemble.

Recently they started doing the same thing. I though oh no, not again. I didn't initially consider there might have been a new cause.  What could that cause be?

Answer (score 10):

So I starting looking into the failure of my 3 point door locks and heard a clanking when trying to put them into the locked position. I realized that the "shootbolts" were slamming against the side of the door. Why?  Was there an internal jam?   A broken parts.

Turns out there is a small bottom plate with a hole that receives the shootbolt (pic attached)  It was full of debris!  I cleaned it out and the locks worked fine again.  Easy as that.  But I almost overlooked it because I had a previous mind-set about what was wrong and what the fix was. Sometimes I just make it too hard. Lesson learned:  Look for the easy/simple stuff first.

[image: pic of bottom locking plate]

Answer (score 0):

Freezing temperatures, wet snow and strong winds managed to cause ice build up in the lower shootbolt hole. May of contributed to the problem after sweeping snow away from doorwall earlier.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. While this does seem to answer the question, reading through [how to write a good answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) would give you some tips to improve it.