# Pella 3-point lock shootbolts don't fully extend

Tags: doors, lock

Sometimes when the handle of the 3-point lock on my Pella door is turned into the lock position the shootbolt at the top does not go up all the way. Then the key will not lock the door. You can reproduce the problem with the door open, so I know it is not a problem of the shootbolt not fitting into the bottom or top plate. I have lubricated the place at the top of the door where the shootbolt pops up.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The OP wants to know why _"...the shootbolt at the top does not go all the way..."_ I assume this means the bolt at the top of the door does not fully extend when the lock handle is actuated.

Comment: Is the 3point mechanism in question Pella proprietary, or who actually *made* the thing?

Comment: Providing pictures and exact model numbers of products in question helps quite a bit in finding a resolution. Also, since this is a Question and Answer forum, actually _asking a question_ (involving a sentence that ends in a question mark `?`) is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have those exact same doors from Pella. They have been a problem for Pella. I posted a couple of years ago about what I found,  Here is a link:
[Pella Door won't lock (3 point lock)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/185751/pella-door-wont-lock-3-point-lock)

A couple of pointers:

1. Make sure the bottom part where the lower shootbolt fits into is very clean with no debris.
2. If the door wasn't used much, you may have to take apart the entire assembly on the edge of the door and lube it up. Don't use WD-40, it doesn't last, since product recommendations are OT here, I won't go there, but there are great products out there, WD-40 just won't last.

Comment: I don't think this is the OP's issue, as the OP wrote "You can reproduce the problem with the door open, so I know it is not a problem of the shootbolt not fitting into the bottom or top plate."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica OK, good point. Then it's a matter of disassembling, lubing, adjusting.  It's a lot of work, I've had to do it on several of my Pella 3 point locking doors.   There are adjustments buried in the covering on the edge.  These doors are not a good product.